# Why can't Pan go Super Saiyan?

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

As the title states, why can't Pan go to Super Saiyan Mode?

We see in the last episode of Pan's grandson turning Super Saiyan while he fights a descendant of Vegeta.  Are female Saiyans not able to turn Super Saiyan?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to this [wiki](http://anime.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Why_can%27t_pan_go_super_saiyan) 
pan never did have to go super saiyan mode.

> [...] basically it's because the creator of Dragonball, Akira Toriyama claims that Pan never had a reason or situation to turn super saiyan. Her debut is at the end of dragonball z, as a little kid, and since Dragonball GT is not based off actual manga, Toriyama only envisioned Pan as a little girl in a time of peace, so there would be no reason for her to become super saiyan. Toriyama has also said that he doesnt exactly know how he would draw a female super-saiyan [...]

Answer (score 10):

Well, according to this [Pan's trivia section](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Pan#Trivia), the **in-real-world reason** seems to be that Akira Toriyama couldn't figure out how to draw a female SSJ.

One of the possible reasons, **in the DB universe**, is that Pan never really trained to become a more powerful warrior. The other kids, through the generations, managed to reach that level quite quickly yes, but they trained a lot too. Pan simply didn't feel that need that much.

The female SSJ appear in the videogames only.

Just for completeness, I discovered that according to an italian collection on the DB franchise, one of the fundamental requirements to become SSJ is to be a male. That would explain why Goku Jr and Vegeta Jr can still become SSJ regardless of the blood being diluted. This has been said across the internet, but there's nothing official about this.

Answer (score 5):

Pan has never done any hard training in the Dragon Ball series. Pan may have her father's (Gohan) saiyan blood in her body, but she is not a full blooded saiyan like her grandfather (Goku). In Dragon Ball MMO (Online) the DB online game (created by Akira Toriyama), states that female saiyans are able to transform into a super saiyan.

In Dragon Ball GT Perfect Files, states that Pan would have a great potential to become a super saiyan. In the first ever canon Dragon Ball movie, Battle of Gods (that came out earlier this year in theaters in Japan), Shenron said, "there are 6 pure saiyans that were able to let Goku to transform into a Super Saiyan God form." These 6 saiyans are: Goku, Gohan, Vegeta, Trunks, Goten, and last but not least Pan (which of course Pan wasn't even born yet, and she still inside her mother's (Videl) stomach).

With the success of the brand new Dragon Ball movie, it's very unclear that there is a rumor about the new Dragon Ball series that was spreading across the internet this year. I don't know if that's true or not, but I hope will definitely see Pan turn into a super saiyan, a female super saiyan for the first time ever in Dragon Ball history.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, the main reason is Toriyama not knowing how to portray a female Super Saiyan, which might also be the reason while the entire offspring of both Goku and Vegeta until the very end of DBZ are exclusively male - and shown capable of transforming into Super Saiyans. 
Since the potential seems to be passed down to the children, Bra and Pan both should be able to pull it off. Again, the question of design gets in the way, and the fact that until some point in GT when things began to go south rapidly, starting with Baby's using of the Ultimate Dragonballs, they lived fairly peaceful lives.

Also, bear in mind that all Saiyan-blooded children shown are halfbreeds or, in Pan's case, only 1/4th Saiyan. Taking Gohan as an example, the human blood inside him significantly dampened his drive to fight and the urge to train, which is why he preferred pursuing an education unlike his father and Vegeta who remain obsessed with improving their physical capabilities even in times of peace as if driven by instinct.

Since from the end of DBZ to the end of the first third of GT the Earth has been peaceful, halfblooded Trunks, Goten and Bra have had no reason whatsoever to train and lacked the drive to do so because circumstances allowed them to live peaceful lives. Pan only trained because of Goku and Mr. Satan's influence but seemed to take it more as a hobby.

In conclusion, given the right circumstances female Saiyans are all but impossible, except for the fact the species is nearly extinct.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because Pan, being female, was always in control of her emotions? Like most woman their emotions area what they can control. Unlike men who have a tendency to lose control and become angry as if it were a instinct. Take Goku, he transformed because of the fact that his best friend was killed therefore losing control of his anger. Vegeta transformed because he was angry that he couldn't surpass Goku and in the end just didn't care if he did. Goten transformed because his Mother (Chichi) kept picking on him through constant sparring sessions. Trunks transformed because of his Daddy issues, but whatever happened with Pan, she never got angry. She got upset but never ever lost control of what she was doing. Well that is my theory anyway.

Comment: Pan cries often in gt and behaves like a spoiled brat sometimes. Besides the issue of designing a ssj female, pan lived a peaceful life. She already had goku, Gohan, vegeta, gotenks, and trunks to protect her from the minimal  conflict of the times. Even the human females from Erath who were martial artists at some point stopped fighting to deal with family.  Not including 18.